# Accessing, and push_back values of a vector from a different class?

Tags: c++

I'm overall confused on how to access a vector, and add values to it from a different class.

I would like to add values into the vector (the vector is private) from a different class. I also want to access the vector in my main() and be able to print it out.

Can anyone give me an example of how this is done?

```
Class A
{
//vector is here - it's a private vector
}
Class B
{
//add values to the vector here
}
main()
{
//access the vector here, and print out the values
}
```

Comment: Time to open up [that C++ book](http://jcatki.no-ip.org/fncpp/Resources) you bought before starting...

Comment: Why is it private if you want to modify and access it from elsewhere? Not that I'm suggesting you should make it public, but your design doesn't seem very well thought out. You will need to get `A` to implement the necessary functions for accessing and modifying the vector. If it's just going to duplicate the entire interface, then why have `A` in the first place? Your question is too broad to answer right now.

Comment: @sftrabbit, it was a challenge by our prof, which I have no idea on how to even approach it.

Comment: Perhaps he wants you to learn about [friend functions and classes](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/friends.html).

Answer (score 0):

If the vector is a private member of `A`, the usual way to provide access is through public member functions of `A` that wrap access to the vector. Generally, you should expose only what access is necessary. Read about encapsulation. There isn't much point in making the vector private if you intend to provide a full public interface to it. If you want just the `B` class to have unfettered access to it (along with `A`'s other members), you can make `B` a [friend class](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/) of `A`.